# Azure function App settings is null after deployment

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions, appsettings

Here is my scenario:

- I have a c# blob trigger azure function (alwaysON set to true).
- I am setting the appsettings of the function app using
  New-AzureRmResource ps cmdlet.
- I am deploying the azure function by calling PUT Rest call on "https://$functionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot" to upload a zip file (which contains run.csx, function.json and bin/*.dll files).
- I use CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(settingKey) to get the appsettings in the *.dll files. I have a IsNullOrWhiteSpace check on these appsettings to throw a ConfigurationErrorsException.

Problem: After deploying, always the first trigger to the azure function fails. It fails with the ConfigurationErrorsException exception which i am throwing if a appsetting is IsNullOrWhiteSpace. 
After about a minute after the first failed trigger, all the subsequent triggers start to be successful.

Is it that it takes time for appsettings to get loaded ? 
Have any of you faced such issue before ? What is the workaround/solution for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be using `CloudConfigurationManager` in Azure App Service, as that component is designed for Cloud Services (a different Azure offering). You should avoid referencing that assembly entirely.

Instead, simply use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSetting"]` to access your app settings.

Comment: Thanks. Is this even applicable for Azure Web App ?

Comment: No, app service includes both web apps and function apps.

Comment: The behaviour is same even after using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x"]. By the way the azure function is on a standard app service plan with AlwaysOn true.

Comment: When you don't get the app setting, can you check if the environment variable by the same name is set? i.e. use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YourSetting")`? Normally they should both be set.

Comment: @David Ebbo: The following Microsoft Azure doc does not make such a strong statement about the specific usage scope for CloudConfigurationManager. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/storage-cloud-configuration-manager-include.md. I have used CloudConfigurationManager in a precompiled Azure function dll deployed on a continuous plan, the same code also runs within a local desktop Console app and also when debugging my Azure function locally. For me CloudConfigurationManager seems to be working as advertised.

Comment: @camelCase I think it works because it has fallback logic to use `ConfigurationManager` when it's not running in a cloud service. But it has no benefits over using the standard pattern, and I seem to recall cases where referencing that assembly caused issues. So the wisdom when using App Service is to not use this at all. It is simply not designed for Azure App Service.